# How a proper way to test with RSpec a unchecked checkbox in PostController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec-rails, pundit

I'm doing this test controller with RSpec on post_controller, but I'm having difficult to evaluate the users who don't have permission for check the categories.

**expect(posting.categories).to have_unchecked_field("Sports")**

This test it's like a way for a user don't hacking the post categories.

The

```
context "restrictions for users on posts who" do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }
    let(:category) { create(:category)}
    let(:posting) { Post.create(title: "State transitions", subtitle: "Can't be hacked.", content: "State transitions now they can't be hacked anymore.", author: user) }

    before :each do
      posting.categories << category
      assign_role!(user, :editor, posting)
      sign_in user
    end

    it  "can edit a post, but not tag them" do
      put :update, { id: :posting.to_param, title: "Editing post for editors!",
                            content: "The editor users, they cannot tag a post",
                            tag_names: "these are tags" },
                    post_id: posting.id

      posting.reload
      expect(posting.tags).to be_empty
    end

    it  "can edit a post, but not check the categories" do
      put :update, { id: :posting.to_param,
                     title: "Editing post for editors!",
                    content: "The editor users, they cannot check categories",
                    category_ids:["Sports"] },
                  post_id: posting.id

      posting.reload

      expect(posting.categories).to have_unchecked_field("Sports")

    end

  end
end
```

form:

```
- if policy(post).change_category?
  = f.association :categories, label: "Select the Categories:", as: :check_boxes , collection: @categories.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, include_hidden: false
```

So I'm using the private method sanitizing_parameters for deleting the parameters if a user don't have a permission.

post_controller.rb

```
def update
    authorize @post, :update?
    @post.author = current_user

    if @post.update(sanitized_parameters)
      flash[:notice] = "Post has been updated."
      redirect_to @post
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Post has not been updated."
      render "edit"
    end
  end

...
private

  def post_params
params.require(:post).permit(:title,
                             :subtitle,
                             :content,
                             :tag_names,
                             :attachment,
                             :attachment_cache,
                             :remove_attachment,
                             :remote_attachment_url,
                             category_ids:[])
  end

  def sanitized_parameters
    whitelisted_params = post_params

    unless policy(@post).change_category?
      whitelisted_params.delete(category_ids:[])
    end

    unless policy(@post).tag?
      whitelisted_params.delete(:tag_names)
    end

    whitelisted_params
  end
```

error:

```
Failures:

  1) PostsController restrictions for users on posts who can edit a post, but not check the categories
     Failure/Error: expect(posting.categories).to have_unchecked_field("Sports")
       expected to find field "Sports" that is not checked but there were no matches
```

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a controller or possibly request test, but Capybara is only for use in feature/system and view tests.  When you attempt to call `have_unchecked_field("Sports")` it should have raised a no method error since you shouldn't even be including the Capybara methods into controller tests.

Since you have included Capybara::DSL into all your tests (assumed) it's taking `posting.categories`, converting it to a string, parsing it as HTML, and then looking for elements in it.  Since `posting.categories` isn't HTML it's never going to work like that.  What you probably want is something like

```
expect(posting.categories).to be_empty
```

Comment: I try this be_empty. And raises this error:
 Failure/Error: expect(posting.categories).to be_empty
       expected `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Category id: 326, name: "Sports", created_at: "2018-04-09 17:42:48", updated_at: "2018-04-09 17:42:48">]>.empty?` to return true, got false

Comment: Yes, I was thinking and this match have_unchecked_field has no sense in controller tests... thank's for reply @Thomas Walpole

Comment: @rld If it's telling you that `posting.categories` is not empty, then your test is either wrong or your code isn't doing what you think it is.  You can see from that error that "Sports" has been added to `posting.categories` which is exactly what you're testing to make sure doesn't happen.

Comment: I do this when try to create a post, and now I'm trying for updating the post. It has something wrong with the updating.

Comment: Well in your `before` block you're adding a category to `posting` - I'm not sure if that defaults to 'Sports' for the category or not -- If it does then you test wouldn't actually be testing anything since the category would already be checked.

Comment: Yes I do a:
`before_action :set_categories, only: [:edit, :update]

def set_categories
    @categories = Category.all.select(:id, :name)
  end`
I pretend to delete the params of the categories like I do on tags.

Comment: I commit the:
`before :each do
      #posting.categories << category`
and pass, there I was adding a category and I put to use a number rather than a string on:
`category_ids:["1"] },`
And pass. This test with checkbox is confusing. For the moment I'll leave it like this. Thank you for your help @Thomas Walpole